# How to change jqplot series display order/logic

Tags: jqplot

Can someone please advise how can I make jqplot charts display series a little bit differently (I am referring to the logic / order not the design).

For example lets say I have something like this:

```
var series1 = [1, 2, 3];
var series2 = [4, 5, 6];
var series3 = [7, 8, 9];

var ticks = ['JAN','FEB','MAR'];
```

The standard plotting will place the first value of every series array in 'JAN', the second in 'FEB' and the third in 'MAR'.

I want to display the entire series1 in 'JAN', series2 in 'FEB' and series3 in 'MAR'.
The arrays may not even be of the same size (series2 and series3 may have more or less elements than series1).

Any advice is apreciated,

Thank you!